# How do I echo this JSON data in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I am using Laravel to call a stored procedure in MySQL. I am trying to iterate over the data that is returned but I can't seem to figure it out. I either get an invalid argument foreach error, or html specialchars error I don't encode my JSON before sending it to the view

My DB call:

```
$data = DB::select('CALL sp_MyClientList()');
```

If I return this to the view

```
return view('my-view.index', compact('data'));
```

I get htmlspecial chars error. OK

so I use:

```
$json = json_encode($data);
```

and I receive this JSON format and send that to the view:

```
return view('my-view.index', compact('json'));

[  {  
"ClientID":24,
"Name":"Client1",
"Balance1":null,
"Balance2":null
},
{  
"ClientID":25,
"Name":"Client2",
"Balance1":24,
"Balance2":0
}]
```

How can I foreach this loop to get the key value pairs inside?

I tried to iterate over the loop twice, but no luck

```
@foreach ($json as $obj)

@for each ($obj as $client)

....

@endforeach

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure has only one layer.

```
@foreach($json as $v)
    {{ $v-> ClientID }} - {{ $v->Name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: invalid argument foreach!

Answer (score 0):

you can use json decode

```
foreach (json_decode($json) as $a)
{
  print_r($a); // this is your area from json response
}
```

or

```
foreach ($json as $a)
{
  print_r($a); // this is your area from json response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can create a function that gets the data and decodes it to an array like this:

```
public function retrievingData($yourVariableHere){
    $data='[  {
    "ClientID":24,
"Name":"Client1",
"Balance1":null,
"Balance2":null
},
{
    "ClientID":25,
"Name":"Client2",
"Balance1":24,
"Balance2":0
}]';

    $data=json_decode($data,true);
    return view('myViewFile',[
        'data' => $data
    ]);   
}
```

For the sake of the example i hardcoded your json just to use the data you provided.

In your function you return the decoded array to the blade and you can echo your result like this:

```
@foreach ($data as $row)
    Client Id: {{$row->ClientID}}<br>
    Name : {{$row->Name}}<br>
    Balance1 data: {{$row->Balance1}}<br>
    Balance2 data: {{$row->Balance2}}<br>
@endforeach
```

Inside a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone needs the answer to this. I dont know if this is right but it did work for me. I had to encode then decode my return from the server then accessing the array.

```
$data = DB::select('CALL sp_myproc');

$json = js_encode($data, true);
$arr = js_decode($data, true);

 return view('myview.index', compact('arr'));

@foreach ($arr as $client)

{{$client['Name'}}

@endforeach
```